Postgresql dump unusable due to late creation of a collation
There seems to be a problem with the order of creation and using a collation in a Postgresql dump. I defined a collation for my database a long time ago. This is used for exactly one column in a table.
With this constellation everything has worked so far, the dump contained the creation of the collation before it was used in the table.
...
CREATE COLLATION public.de_pos (provider = icu, locale = 'de-DE-u-kn-true');
...
CREATE TABLE public.kalkulation_position (
    pos character varying COLLATE public.de_pos,
...

Now I have defined a DB view that also uses the column that contains the collation. When I now create a dump, there is an error during the restore due to a non-existent collation. The view (with the column that uses the collation) should be created before the collation is created. This leads to the error.
...
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public."mengenübersicht_global" AS
SELECT
    NULL::character varying COLLATE public.de_pos AS lv_position,
...
CREATE COLLATION public.de_pos (provider = icu, locale = 'de-DE-u-kn-true');
...
CREATE TABLE public.kalkulation_position (
    pos character varying COLLATE public.de_pos,
...

Now I can certainly do without the collation in the view, but isn't this a fundamental problem and may have to be solved differently?
Here is some additional info as requested:

with
ON_ERROR_STOP=off
The view is created and populated and the whole restore process finished successfully. Otherwise, the process stops with the following error:
 ERROR:  collation "public.de_pos" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
 ZEILE 12:     NULL::character varying COLLATE public.de_pos AS lv_posi...


versions:
source system: pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 16.3 (Debian 16.3-1.pgdg110+1)
target system: psql (PostgreSQL) 16.2 (Homebrew)

commands:
pg_dump --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=steel42 --file=steel42prod_2024-09-05.sql --clean --no-owner --superuser=steel42 --if-exists --role=steel42 --exclude-table-data=document_storage --verbose steel42prod

psql --echo-all --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=steel42 --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on steel42 <steel42prod_2024-09-05.sql





Did the view actually get created? 2) Question needs more information. Add as update to question text: a) Postgres version being dumped from and Postgres version being restored to. b) The versions of pg_dump and pg_restore used. c) The pg_dump and pg_restore commands used.


Right; I cannot reproduce that with v17.

How did you create the backup, what was the exact command?

Please provide a runnable example.  Matched parentheses, no dangling commas, use semicolons to end statements, and if you need comments use the comment syntax --  or /* */ not ....

I've added the requested informations as update to the question text.
